# Java login through LDAP

Tags: ldap, java, login

I am starting to write an application for our office and the first step is authentication through LDAP where all users already exist. Everything I need is a code in Java to check if the pair `<nick,password>` is right. Google found me many links, but I think that I will find here the most sofisticate, short and up to date solution (I don't want to read all articles like 2 whole days to do something so simple).

I have written many dkBs of code in C++, but in Java I am total noob and I haven't coded anything with LDAP yet so try to be simple if speaking in Java and LDAP terms if possible.

Comment: You are totally wrong here. This site is for system administrators, not for software developers (see the [FAQ]). [SO] might be for you, but check their site and FAQ first.

Comment: I note that your account is  blocked from asking questions on stackoverflow. Please don't ask any more Off Topic programming related questions on serverfault as the same will happen here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack Overflow is the right site. In the meantime, using the [UnboundID LDAP SDK](https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldapsdk/):

```
try {
    LDAPConnection ldapConnection = new LDAPConnection(host,port,bindDN,bindPassword);
} catch (LDAPException ex) {
    handle exception ...
}
```

or

```
try {
    LDAPConnection ldapConnection = new LDAPConnection(host,port);
    SimpleBindRequest bindRequest = new SimpleBindRequest(bindDN,bindPassword);
    final BindResult bindResult = ldapConnection.bind(bindRequest);
} catch (LDAPException ex) {
    handle exception ...
}
```

for simple BIND requests. SASL binds are also handled by the LDAP SDK.

Comment: OK, I was searching the net and the majority told me that UnboundID LDAP is the simplest, clearest and cleanest way to do it. I can't try it yet, because there is not the guy which understands networking, so I don't know the host and port. But this is the answer I was looking for. I am banned on stackoverflow btw :D

Comment: I am trying to use that LDAP, but I am not sure if I build my application through Ant with use of UnboundID if it will run on other computers without it installed as well. I am new in Java, so I don't know how the use of libraries work.